# C++ shared pointer being created over and over again

Tags: c++, function, unit-testing, pointers, googletest

I have the following code that for some reason terminates on the first iteration:

```
struct Node
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;
    uint id;
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> neighbours;
    Eigen::Vector3d position;
};

TEST(MathUtilsTests, DjikstraNodeTest)
{
    std::vector<Node::NodePtr> nodes;
    nodes.resize(10'000);
    auto first = make_shared<Node>();
    first->id = 0;
    first->position = Eigen::Vector3d(0,0,0);
    nodes[0] = first;
    cout << "check1" << endl;
    for(uint i=1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << "check2" << endl;
        for(uint j=0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << "check3" << endl;
            Node n = {};
            Node::NodePtr node = make_shared<Node>(n);
            cout << node << endl;
            node->id = i + j;
            node->neighbours.push_back(nodes[i]);
            node->position = Eigen::Vector3d(i, j, 0);
            nodes[i]->neighbours.push_back(node);
            nodes[i + j] = node;
        }
    }

    ASSERT_FALSE(true);
}
```

Output:

```
[ RUN      ] MathUtilsTests.DjikstraNodeTest
check1
check2
check3
0x555c9bb50ea0
```

I don't understand how that loop is terminating early. If I comment things out such that the inner loop's body is:

```
        cout << "check3" << endl;
        Node n = {};
        Node::NodePtr node = make_shared<Node>(n);
        cout << node << endl;
```

I get:

```
...
check3
0x55e5610d2ea0
check3
0x55e5610d2ea0
check3
0x55e5610d2ea0
check3
0x55e5610d2ea0
check3
0x55e5610d2ea0
check3
...
```

Why is my shared pointer always the same?
How can that loop terminate early?

I am very confused. The `TEST` macro is google test's test.

Comment: It looks like `nodes[i]` is uninitialized.  That's likely the reason you terminate early (via an exception being caught, probably, or your program simply crashing).  When you comment out the bits that store a copy of the shared pointer somewhere, the memory is freed by the shared pointer going out of scope every iteration, so it's entirely plausible that the memory allocator will give you the same address for every new object.

Comment: `nodes[i]` is the shared pointer equivalent of `nullptr` so `nodes[i]->neighbours.push_back(node);` is an error.

Comment: Yes both of you are correct, I forgot that resizing the vector does not initialized the pointers